# Работа с пользователем после авторизации

Tags: c#, mvc

Как я могу создать дополнительный список в `HttpContext.User.Identity`.

К примеру после авторизации я могу получить `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

Как мне записать свою информацию "рядом" с `Name` например `List<string> TEST`? чтобы я его мог получить так: `HttpContext.User.Identity.TEST`

Важен еще момент, что я в представлении могу вытянуть `User.Identity.Name`... с `TEST` нужно то же самое

На данный момент решений не нашел...буду рад любой информции

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.User.Identity` имеет тип [IIdentity](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iidentity?view=netframework-4.8), который в .NET из коробки. Плюс значение этого свойства формируется под капотом.Поэтому получить дополнительную информацию о пользователе так, как Вы этого хотите, не получится.

Однако никто не мешает Вам создать свой [Claim](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.6.php). Либо использовать свои таблицы и классы для этой информации и связать их со стандартными по какому-нибудь ключу (например, какой-нибудь `user_id`, уникальный логин и т.д.). Но, последнее крайне нежелательно, т.к. это велосипед.

Comment: Эх, начало было правильное, а потом ушли не туда. Нужно создать свой Claims

Comment: на счет стандартных таблиц не понял...у меня нет никаких стандартных таблиц

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц у вас нет таблицы dbo.AspNetUsers?

Comment: @tCode нет конешно...я ж не юзаю стандартный `UserIdentity`. Просто после авторизации инфа о пользователе записывается в `HttpContext.User.Identity`...так вот мне нужно "расширить" его

Comment: Даже если так, то всё равно способа решить Вашу задачу только два и я их описал в ответе.

Comment: @AK но работа с `Claim`мами возможно, если я отнаследуюсь от `UserIdentity` и буду работать в `userManager`... а я хотел бы этого не использовать

Comment: Почему Вы не хотите использовать `UserManager`?

Comment: @Streletz потому что для этого мне нужно отнаследоваться от `Identity`